# correlated delete performance problems

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

In my Access DB (inside a C# app), I initially had this query:

```
DELETE 
FROM ModelRule 
WHERE RuleID NOT IN (SELECT RuleID FROM Rule)
```

With 700K rules this is intolerably slow. So I resorted to C# looping:

```
foreach ( DataRow row in dtRulesToPurge.Rows ) {
    [pseudocode:] "DELETE FROM ModelRule WHERE RuleID = " + row["ID"];
    [pseudocode:] Give user feedback/progressbar/counts
}
```

The `foreach` seems faster, but mainly (at least) I can give users feedback via progress bar. This approach takes minutes. The correlated subquery takes *at least minutes*, but I always gave up and killed it before it actually finished - I suspect it takes longer.

BUT I have a little tickle in my mind that says there may be a FAST way to do these deletes via a better subquery or some kind of join, or etc, that would be far better than either of my 2 approaches above.

Would love to get your thoughts.

Comment: You may want to try a Left Outer Join.  I do not think it is faster but you can try : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer `NOT EXISTS`, so I would write:

```
DELETE FROM ModelRule 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Rule
                  WHERE ModelRule.RuleID  = RULE.RuleID
                 );
```

Then for performance, you want an index on `RULE(RuleID)`.